# Intercept COM dllhost.exe invocation

Tags: c++, com, intel-pin

I'm trying to instrument a COM DLL with [Intel Pin](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool/). Unfortunately Intel Pin is designed for instrumenting standalone [processes](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/index.html#EX), not DLLs.

So my question is - is it possible to influence the command line that is used by COM to start the inproc server host (dllhost.exe), so that I can invoke pin.exe with dllhost.exe as an argument? Or is the invocation of dllhost.exe hardcoded into Windows, which would mean my idea is futile?

Comment: Not hard-coded, it is in the registry.  You need the AppId guid, declared in the CLSID registry key.  Then look it up in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\AppID.  The DllSurrogate value tells it that it needs to be hosted, when the value is empty then it will be dllhost.exe.  You can change that to another executable.  Not limited to a copy of dllhost.exe with a different name, whatever trigger you need.

Answer (score 2):

DLLHost.exe is an example of a DLL surrogate which allows you to instantiate a DLL COM server in a separate executable. You can specify an arbitrary executable to use using the [DllSurrogateExecutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694509(v=vs.85).aspx) registry key and you could implement your own DLL surrogate executable [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225(v=vs.85).aspx) which uses Pin directly.

Of course a separate problem is how your COM object is created. DLL Surrogates are only used if the class is registered against an AppID which specifies it can use a DLL surrogate *and* the creator of the COM object specifies CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER to CoCreateInstance et al. You might need to modify the caller to change the context if that's the case.

In order to work out what AppID your class is registered under you can use some tools such as OleView, however it's not too hard to do from the registry editor. If you get the CLSID GUID, do a search for that under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\GUID`. Under there you might find an AppID value. This is a GUID which points to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\GUID2` and that contains whether it's registered as a DLL surrogate and where you can put your DllSurrogateExecutable key.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. Unfortunately writing a [custom surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682432(v=vs.85).aspx) seems complicated :) But certainly doable.